# Accessing an array of images into a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, dom

I have written a script and  need to replace the text strings in the array with images i.e (`1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`). I seem not to referencing the image object correctly and is parsing as string.

I want to replace this bit in the code with images.
From:

```
["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
["Un", "Deux", "Trois", "Quatre"],
["eins", "zwet", "dret", "vier"]
```

To:

```
["<img src=\"1.jpg\"", "<img src=\"2.jpg\"", "<img src=\"3.jpg\"", "<img src=\"4.jpg\""],
["<img src=\"5.jpg\"", "<img src=\"6.jpg\"", "<img src=\"7.jpg\"", "<img src=\"8.jpg\""],
["<img src=\"9.jpg\"", "<img src=\"10.jpg\"", "<img src=\"11.jpg\"","<img src=\"12.jpg\""]
```

```
    //Author : Alexander Adu-Sarkodie
    //To be used with acknowledgement

    function createTable(data) {
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.style.border = "1px solid #ffcc33";
        var thead = document.createElement("thead");
        thead.style.padding = "5px";
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");
            th.style.border = "2px solid #ff0000";
            var newText = document.createTextNode(data[0][i]);
            th.appendChild(newText);
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        thead.appendChild(tr);
        table.appendChild(thead);

        var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement("td");
                td.style.padding = "5px";
                td.style.border = "2px solid #00ff00";
                var newText = document.createTextNode(data[i][j]);
                td.appendChild(newText);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
        }
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        return table;
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var table = createTable([
    ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
    ["Un", "Deux", "Trois", "Quatre"],
    ["eins", "zwet", "dret", "vier"]
    ]);
        document.body.appendChild(table)
    }
```

Comment: What's that weird half-html-string array? Why don't you use an array of the src urls?

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NXvdm/)?

```
var images = ["one", "two", "doesn't", "matter"];

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {

    images[i] = "<img src=\"" + (i+1) + ".jpg\" />";

}

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {

    alert(images[i]);

}​
```